# Undefined index: core_website in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

I migrated magento 1.9 to 2.3

While giving **setup:upgrade** command i got the below error

**Notice: Undefined index: core_website in /vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 152**

can you please help me out from this issue.

Comment: check this please https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/368409/55221

Answer (score 8):

Probably, there is a foreign key to core_website table.

You can find that key with this query.

```sql
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME,
    CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
    REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME,
    REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'core_website';
```

You should drop that foreign key;

```sql
ALTER TABLE <table_name> DROP FOREIGN KEY <key_name>;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: This answer helped me figure out the solution to a similar problem. Thanks a lot.